# fix JPA refused to findUserByUsername

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to use spring security to add authentication and authorization to my api but JPA refused to findUserByUsername. It's(JPA) returning null even though the user is in the database.

**Please Note that the app runs fine but when I try to login with a user this exception raise**

**Please view the error and source code below**

**error**

```
2022-03-03 05:06:48.427 ERROR 9024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.s.f.CustomUserAuthenticationFilter   : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: User with email not found!
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:518) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at com.maxapp.server.filter.CustomUserAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CustomUserAuthenticationFilter.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: User with email not found!
    at com.maxapp.server.service.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.maxapp.server.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c230548a.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at com.maxapp.server.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c176907.loadUserByUsername(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

**Source Code**

**Model Classes**

**User**

```
package com.maxapp.server.model;


import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import static javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER;


@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="user_sequence",
            sequenceName="user_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )

    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "user_sequence"
    )
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name="username", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name="password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    public User(){
    }

    public User(String name, String username, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
package com.maxapp.server.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Repo**

**UserRepo**

```
package com.maxapp.server.repository;

import com.maxapp.server.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    User findUserById(Long id);
    User findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

**RoleRepo**

```
package com.maxapp.server.repository;

import com.maxapp.server.model.Role;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role,Long> {
    Role findRoleByName(String name);
}
```

**Service**

**UserService**

```
package com.maxapp.server.service;

import com.maxapp.server.model.Role;
import com.maxapp.server.model.User;
import com.maxapp.server.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.maxapp.server.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Service @RequiredArgsConstructor @Transactional
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        if(user==null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("User with email not found!");
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role ->{
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        });

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),authorities);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User createUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public Role saveRole(Role role){
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    public void addRoleToUser(Long id,String name){

        User user = userRepository.findUserById(id);
        Role role = roleRepository.findRoleByName(name);

        user.getRoles().add(role);

    }


    public User getSingleUser(Long id) {
        boolean exist = userRepository.existsById(id);
        if(!exist){
            throw new IllegalStateException("User with id : " + id + " not found.");
        }

        return userRepository.findUserById(id);
    }

    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        boolean exist = userRepository.existsById(id);
        if(!exist){
            throw new IllegalStateException("User with id : " + id + " not found.");
        }

        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void updateUser(Long id, String name) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalStateException("User with id : " + id + " not found."));
        if(name != null && name.length()>0 && !(name.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getName()))){
            user.setName(name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

**UserController**

```
package com.maxapp.server.controller;

import com.maxapp.server.model.Role;
import com.maxapp.server.model.User;
import com.maxapp.server.service.UserService;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/v1")
public class UserController {
 private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path="users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping(path="users")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }

    @PostMapping(path="roles")
    public Role createRole(@RequestBody Role role){
        return userService.saveRole(role);
    }

    @PostMapping(path="users/roles")
    public void addRoleToUser(@RequestBody RoleForm role){
        userService.addRoleToUser(role.getId(),role.getName());
    }



    @GetMapping(path="users/{id}")
    public User getSingleUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        return userService.getSingleUser(id);
    }

    @PutMapping(path="users/{id}")
    public void updateUser(
            @PathVariable("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name
    ){
        userService.updateUser(id,name);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path="users/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
         userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

}

@Data
class RoleForm{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**Filter**

**CustomUserAuthenticationFilter**

```
package com.maxapp.server.filter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String email = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email,password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)authResult.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("Maxwell1".getBytes());
        String access_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+10*60*1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURI())
                .withClaim("roles",user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        String refresh_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+30*60*1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURI())
                .sign(algorithm);

        response.setHeader("access_token",access_token);
        response.setHeader("refresh_token",refresh_token);

    }
}
```

**Security**

**SecurityConfig**

```
package com.maxapp.server.security;

import com.maxapp.server.filter.CustomUserAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.addFilter(new CustomUserAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));
    }


    @Bean

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**Application Class**

```
package com.maxapp.server;

import com.maxapp.server.model.Role;
import com.maxapp.server.model.User;
import com.maxapp.server.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runs(UserService userService){

        return  args ->{

            userService.saveRole(new Role("Admin"));
            userService.saveRole(new Role("Student"));


            userService.createUser(new User("Maxwell","mall@gamil.com","1234"));
            userService.createUser(new User("Maxwel","ma1ll@gamil.com","1234"));

            userService.addRoleToUser(1L,"Admin");
            userService.addRoleToUser(2L,"Student");
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Can not see where `loadUserByUsername` is being used.

Comment: What is the database you are using? What is the type and size of the `username` column in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing @gmail.com from my username solved my problem.

Actually the problem was findUserByUsername method was expecting string but I was passing Gmail.

Thank you all for your quick responses. I do appreciate you all!

Answer (score 0):

findUserByUsername will not work
either use JPA-Query using

```
@Query("your required query")
```

OR
make it `findByUsername(String username)`

I would recommend to use [JPA-Buddy](https://www.jpa-buddy.com/) Extension to omit these kind of errors

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: please share code segment you have updated

also bypass the authentication-part for now
in order to get the root cause

Comment: `@Query("select u from User u where u.username = ?1")
    User findByUsername(String username);`

Comment: That finder method is perfectly valid, the `User` part will be ignored. If the query method cannot be parsed the application simply won't start.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the method should be:

```
Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: That won't change a thing, it will now return `null` or the `User` changing it to `Optional` will only result in an empty `Optional` or a filled one. It doesn't change a bit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).